# Linear combination of Frobenius powers contains roots of polynomial

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

> Let $F$ be an $n-$degree extension of $\mathbb{F}_q$ and let $f(x)\in F[x]$. Let $$g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_if(x)^{q^i}$$ with $a_i\in F$. Let
>   $\alpha\in F$ be a root of $g$, prove that $\alpha$ is a root of $f$.

I'm studying an algorithm called **ZZ** for solving certain systems of polynomial equations over $GF(k)$, and the validity of this algorithm depends on this claim. Moreover, the $a_i$ are allowed later to be terms of the form $x^{q^j}$ with $j=0,...,n-1$, and the result is still true. Any suggestion?

Comment: In light of my answer I suspect that a critical assumption is missing. Please check.

Comment: Thank you very much. The possible assumption that's missing is the fact that the coefficients are not random, but they come from certain Gaussian reduction process. The algorithm is proposed in the following paper, it'd be great if you take a little time and try to help me, thanks again: https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/038.pdf

Comment: I didn't quite see this in my admittedly quick read of the manuscript. Wasn't their point to turn a system of polynomial equations in $n$ variables over $GF(q)$ to a single equation over $GF(q^n)$? Not entirely a new thing, but anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false as stated. For a counterexample consider the simple case of $f(x)=x$ and
$a_0=a_1=\cdots=a_{n-1}=1.$ Then we have
$$
g(x)=x+x^q+x^{q^2}+\cdots+x^{q^{n-1}}=tr^F_E(x),
$$
which is the trace function from the field $F=\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ to the subfield $E=\Bbb{F}_q$. More precisely, the restriction of the polynomial function $g$ to $F$ is the trace.

The trace function is a surjective $E$-linear function from $F$ to $E$, so by rank-nullity theorem there are $q^{n-1}$ elements $y\in F$ such that $g(y)=0$. OTOH $x=0$ is the only zero in $F$ of the polynomial $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Excelent answer. I discovered that the result is not necessary for the algorithm to work. In fact, what's true is that any root of $f$ is a root of $g$, so, finding the roots of $g$ will allow us to restrict the possible roots of $f$. Thanks again.